Populate "next review date" knowledge article field
How does everyone utilize the "next review date" field to automatically send an email/alert etc. to article owners?
I have been trying to use record triggered flow to populate next review date based on the last published date. I was trying this in a trail org, Happy to share my flow in pdf, while debugging the date is getting populated, but when I test it in trail org, it is not getting populated.
I have tried with apex, below is my code, but unable to solve
Any help is much appreciated!
trigger KnowledgeArticleTrigger on Knowledge__kav (after update) {
List<Knowledge__kav> articlesToUpdate = new List<Knowledge__kav>();

for (Knowledge__kav article : Trigger.new) {
    // Get the old version of the article
    Knowledge__kav oldArticle = Trigger.oldMap.get(article.Id);
    
    // Log the status of the old and new article
    System.debug('Old Article PublishStatus: ' + oldArticle.PublishStatus);
    System.debug('New Article PublishStatus: ' + article.PublishStatus);
    System.debug('Is Latest Version: ' + article.IsLatestVersion);

    // Check if PublishStatus changed to 'Online' and it is the latest version
    if (oldArticle.PublishStatus != 'Online' && article.PublishStatus == 'Online' && article.IsLatestVersion == true) {
        // Log the current and updated LastPublishedDate
        System.debug('Old Article LastPublishedDate: ' + oldArticle.LastPublishedDate);
        System.debug('New Article LastPublishedDate: ' + article.LastPublishedDate);

        // Update the NextReviewDate
        article.NextReviewDate = article.LastPublishedDate.addDays(120);
        System.debug('NextReviewDate set to: ' + article.NextReviewDate);
        articlesToUpdate.add(article);
    }
}

if (!articlesToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
    update articlesToUpdate;
    System.debug('Updated articles with new NextReviewDate: ' + articlesToUpdate);
}

}
Test Code
@isTest
public class KnowledgeArticleTriggerTest {
    @isTest
    static void testKnowledgeArticleUpdateAndPublish() {
        // Create and publish an article
        Knowledge__kav newArticle = new Knowledge__kav(
            Title = 'Test Article',
            UrlName = 'test-article',
            Language = 'en_US',
            Summary = 'Test summary'
    );
    
    Test.startTest();
    insert newArticle;
    
    System.debug('Article inserted with ID: ' + newArticle.Id);
    System.debug('Inserted article: ' + newArticle);
    
    // Retrieve the inserted article to get its KnowledgeArticleId
    newArticle = [SELECT Id, KnowledgeArticleId FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE Id = :newArticle.Id];
    
    // Publish the article
    KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(newArticle.KnowledgeArticleId, true);
    System.debug('Article published with KnowledgeArticleId: ' + newArticle.KnowledgeArticleId);
    
    // Retrieve the published article
    Knowledge__kav publishedArticle = [SELECT Id, PublishStatus, IsLatestVersion, LastPublishedDate, NextReviewDate 
                                        FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE Id = :newArticle.Id];
    
    System.debug('Fetched published article: ' + publishedArticle);
    
    // Create a draft article from the published article
    String draftArticleId = KbManagement.PublishingService.editOnlineArticle(newArticle.KnowledgeArticleId, true);
    
    System.debug('Draft created with ID: ' + draftArticleId);
    
    // Retrieve the draft article
    Knowledge__kav draftArticle = [SELECT Id, KnowledgeArticleId FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE Id = :draftArticleId];
    
    System.debug('Draft article: ' + draftArticle);
    
    draftArticle.Title = 'Updated Test Article';
    update draftArticle;
    
    System.debug('Draft article updated with ID: ' + draftArticle.Id);
    System.debug('Draft article: ' + draftArticle);
    
    // Publish the updated article
    KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(draftArticle.KnowledgeArticleId, true);
    System.debug('Draft article re-published with KnowledgeArticleId: ' + draftArticle.KnowledgeArticleId);
    
    // Retrieve the published updated article
    Knowledge__kav updatedArticle = [SELECT Id, PublishStatus, IsLatestVersion, LastPublishedDate, NextReviewDate 
                                      FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE Id = :draftArticle.Id];
    
    System.debug('Fetched updated article: ' + updatedArticle);
    
    Test.stopTest();
    
    // Assert the publish status and next review date
    System.assertEquals('Online', updatedArticle.PublishStatus, 'Failed to publish article');
    System.assertEquals(updatedArticle.LastPublishedDate.addDays(120), updatedArticle.NextReviewDate, 'NextReviewDate is incorrect');
}

}

Have you tried debugging the flow? https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/flow-testing-and-distribution/make-sure-your-flow-works

Hi there! Can you please add screenshots of the flow that you created for this and your debugging results as well. This will help us in assisting you with your issue more effectively.

@AdriaanVanNiekerk Thanks for the response, I have added the apex code, it looks like publishArticle is not firing the trigger.
